# How can I see on the API docs what is the Schema being returned inside a list?

Tags: swagger, openapi, pydantic, django-ninja

How can I see on the API docs what is the Schema being returned inside a list?

```
response={
    200: list[PersonSchema]
}
```

It troubles me that by looking the docs the information that the content of this response is a list of type PersonSchema is lost.

---

**Example with code:**

```
class PersonSchema(Schema):
  id: int
  name: str
  age: int
```

On an endpoint that returns a single object of the Schema above:

```
@playbook_routes_api.get(
    "/person/{person_id}",
    response={
        200: PersonSchema
    }
)
def get_person_by_id(request, person_id: int):
    return 200, PersonSchema(id=1, name='Brian', age=12)
```

The API explicity shows the Schema and its contents:

[image]

However. On an endpoint that returns a list of the same Schema:

```
@playbook_routes_api.get(
    "/person/",
    response={
        200: list[PersonSchema]
    }
)
def get_persons(request):
    return 200, [PersonSchema(id=1, name='Brian', age=12), PersonSchema(id=2, name='John', age=31)]
```

This time the API shows no information about the Schema at all. There is a general 'Response' and an 'items' atribute inside it. By looking just at this endpoint it is not possible to know what is the Schema being returned.

[image]

Comment: The response indicates it's an array<objects> and the items keyword is the representation of the object in the list, which matches your Personschema.   Can you explain why you think the list representation is not represented?

Comment: You may need to add the `title` attribute to your schema if you want the Swagger Editor to show the name of the schema being used.

Comment: @JeremyFiel the schema do not appear. The tab is called 'Schema' on API docs but differently from the case where just one item is returned there is no 'Schema'.

Comment: @JeremyFiel is there a title atribute for the entire Schema? If it do exist why I do not need it when returning just one element?

Comment: Yes you can add a title to any schema.  This is a design decision by the framework you are using. For some schemas they show the class name and others they don't. I'm not sure why they do that. Make an issue on their GitHub repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Django-Ninja](https://django-ninja.dev/), the [`Schema` classes](https://django-ninja.dev/guides/response/)  do not natively support a `title` attribute directly within the class body. Instead, Django-Ninja schemas can include meta information through a [`Config` inner class](https://django-ninja.dev/guides/response/config-pydantic/), which is a common pattern for Pydantic models (upon which Django-Ninja's schemas are based).

However, while Pydantic allows for a `title` attribute in the `Config` class to specify a title for the model in the generated schema, this title's visibility in the Swagger UI generated by Django-Ninja might not behave as one might intuitively expect.

```py
from django_ninja import Schema

class PersonSchema(Schema):
    id: int
    name: str
    age: int

    class Config:
        title = "Person"  # Attempt to add a title for Swagger UI documentation
```

As [Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8564731/jeremy-fiel) mentioned, whether the class name or the `title` attribute's value is used in the documentation is up to the framework's design. That means that even with the `title` specified, Django-Ninja (or more accurately, the Swagger UI it generates) may not consistently display this title in the way you expect across different contexts (e.g., single object vs. list of objects).

Adding a `title` in the `Config` might not have the intended effect on the Swagger UI documentation without explicit support or acknowledgment of this attribute by Django-Ninja for this specific purpose. It is beneficial for schema clarity in general (especially in the generated OpenAPI schema) but might not resolve the specific issue of schema visibility in lists.

That is why Jeremy suggests raising this as a question or feature request in the [Django-Ninja GitHub repository](https://github.com/vitalik/django-ninja).

Comment: I do not get it. Where your suggested configuration goes? I am using Django-Ninja and the documentation only talks about the use of an extra_api to further document de API doc, but even on this extra_api there is no way to create the suggested component and then reference it.

Comment: @Rodolfo Good point. I have rewritten the answer to address the use of Django-Ninja.

Comment: Great. I have followed the suggestions and took this issue to Django-NInja's GitHub repo.

Comment: @Rodolfo good call. I will follow that issue #1089 with interest.